# how i can convert php array to json format

Tags: php, arrays, json

hello for example i have bellow json format. i need generate a php array to build this json from that

```
{
"posts":
    [
    {
    "detial" : {
        "titel": "web design",
        "date-publish" : "2015-02-08",
        "pic-thumbnail" : "small-web-desing-jpg",
        "pic-medium" : "medium-web-desing-jpg"
    },
    "content" : {
        "description" : "description web design post",
        "content" : "web design is modern technology in world"
    }
    }
    ]
}
```

please show  An example of that PHP Array build this json

Comment: `$obj = json_encode($your_string_here, true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is Easy** !

Simply use PHP's `json_decode()` function to acheive that.

Finally, save your json_encode() return array to a variable.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [detial] => Array
                        (
                            [titel] => web design
                            [date-publish] => 2015-02-08
                            [pic-thumbnail] => small-web-desing-jpg
                            [pic-medium] => medium-web-desing-jpg
                        )

                    [content] => Array
                        (
                            [description] => description web design post
                            [content] => web design is modern technology in world
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$results = json_decode('{

  "posts": [{

    "detial" : {

      "titel": "web design",
        "date-publish" : "2015-02-08",
        "pic-thumbnail" : "small-web-desing-jpg",
        "pic-medium" : "medium-web-desing-jpg"

    },

    "content" : {

      "description" : "description web design post",
      "content" : "web design is modern technology in world"

    }

  }]

}', true);

echo "<pre>".print_r($results, true)."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP function json_decode() for generate a php array.

```
$jsonData = json_decode('{
 "posts": [{ 

   "detial" : {

     "titel": "web design",

       "date-publish" : "2015-02-08",
       "pic-thumbnail" : "small-web-desing-jpg",
       "pic-medium" : "medium-web-desing-jpg"

   },
   "content" : {

       "description" : "description web design post",
       "content" : "web design is modern technology in world"

   }

 }]
 }',true);

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($jsonData);
```